# Inserting Delimiter into PowerShell Output

Tags: powershell

The result of `Get-Process -Name explorer | select  Handles,WS,CPU,Id,ProcessName | ft -HideTableHeaders` returns the following output:

```
2623 255336448 178.125 10080 explorer
```

In order to ingest this data into a third party system, I need to pipe delimit the result as such:

```
2623|255336448|178.125|10080|explorer
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
(Get-Process explorer |
  Select-Object Handles,Ws,CPU,ID,ProcessName |
  ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation |
  Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '"',''
```

Only use `ft` (`Format-Table`) for easy viewing in the PowerShell console (it's not good for sending data to other applications, because then you would have to undo the formatting - so don't format in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

To offer a more concise (and slightly faster) alternative to [Bill Stewart's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50535791/45375):

```
Get-Process -Name explorer | ForEach-Object { 
  $(foreach ($prop in 'Handles', 'WS', 'CPU', 'Id', 'ProcessName') { $_.$prop }) -join '|'
}
```

- `foreach ($prop in 'Handles', 'WS', 'CPU', 'Id', 'ProcessName') { $_.$prop }` outputs all the properties of interest for each process object (`$_`, the input object at hand provided by the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet).
- `$(...)` collects them as an `[object[]]` array, which ...
- ... enables that array's use as the LHS of the `-join` operator in order to join  the array's elements with `|` as the separator to form a single string.

Overall, you get a single string per input object, as desired.